# Partitioned Desktop looses Ubuntu 18.04 DSL wired/connection every time Windows 10 updates

Tags: boot, networking, dual-boot, partitioning

Every single time the Windows 10 partition updates, when I go back and start in Ubuntu my wired connection disappears.
And I am forced to restart with WIFI and do a recovery of the network in GRUB (sorry I am not sure how to explain this.. that booting phase where you get to choose the partition, I go into advance mode and then go enable networking).

Is there a way to avoid having to do this every single time windows 10 updates?

I run Ubuntu 18.04.

Thank you

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This happens because Windows overwrite your system in every update that is why I use separate disks for separate OSes, like my SSD for Windows and HardDrive for Ubuntu, The version of Ubuntu doesn't matter in that case. So just install on another drive.

Comment: Where Ubuntu or Windows are installed is irrelevant.